# Thread in C# causing infinite loop and blocks my application

Tags: c#

I have created a Thread in which i just move a radiobutton from left to right of the form.
This runs, but my application get's blocked, i can't move the form around, nothing(I thought this was the reason for creating threads, to make multiple things at the same time)
Here is my code and I hope you understand what I asked. Thanks in advance

```
    private void moveRight( )
    {
        radioButton1.Left++;
    }
    private void moveLeft()
    {
        radioButton1.Left--;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (radioButton1.Left != this.ClientSize.Width - 10)
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(moveRight));
                }
                else
                {
                    moveRight();
                }
            }
            while (radioButton1.Left != 10)
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(moveLeft));
                }
                else
                {
                    moveLeft();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(run)); 
        t.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I user Threads before, but not with Invoke, so I thought if I use Invoke in a Thread it will execute in the Thread I invoke it in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `Invoke` on a control you're telling it to run the provided code in the UI thread.

Given that, your code is starting a new thread, and then in that thread telling the UI thread to go run a bunch of code that runs forever.

Now you see why the UI thread is blocked I hope?

You need to have your primary while loop in the background thread (i.e. not inside of the `Invoke` call) and limit the `Invoke` call to specifically the small block of code that is updating the UI.

Comment: I'd suggest also changing the exit condition, != to <=

Comment: I understoo what you said, but how can I make this code run in the Thread I created while still using Invoke, I need to user Invoke because else I get an ilegal crossThreadException because the radiobutton was created in the UI Thread.

Comment: @user2175339 That's *exactly* what I explain how to do in my answer.  See the very last sentence.  You need to use `Invoke`, but you need to change where you place it.  Rather than putting all of your code into an `Invoke` call you need to invoke only small UI updates, while leaving the bulk of the work outside of the `Invoke` call.

Comment: I updated the code. It runs, but it doesn't run very smooth, what am still doing wrong?

Comment: @user2175339 Your computer is able to execute that loop *very* quickly.  It's able to update the UI many millions of times per second.  The monitor can't keep up with that many updates.  You need some way of slowing it down.  While it's not an ideal solution, a simple starting place would be to add a `Thread.Sleep` call to the background worker.  A more robust solution would be to use a `Timer`  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few problems with your approach:

1. Your code in the thread never ends.. you have an infinite loop
2. Even though you are creating a thread, you are still running everything on the UI thread (using Invoke)

Those 2 combined means that you are essentially infinitely blocking the UI thread.

Essentially, this:

```
while (true)
{
    while (radioButton1.Left != this.ClientSize.Width - 10)
    {
        moveRight();
    }
    while (radioButton1.Left != 10)
    {
        moveLeft();
    }
}
```

will never end. And since it's invoked on the UI thread, the UI will be blocked indefinitely while just updating the Left coordinate of your control, without anything actually being rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I user Threads before, but not with Invoke, so I thought if I use Invoke in a Thread it will execute in the Thread I invoke it in