# eC# Multithreading Control UI

Tags: c#

This function runs in an other thread.
I want to control some CheckBoxes.
The CheckBoxes are in an ArrayList
I have no idea why this is not working

```
private void aktu_pin()
    {
        NetworkStream ns = server.GetStream();
        int recv;
        ControlUi ui = new ControlUi(ChangeCheckbox);

        data = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

            if ((data[0] == 0) && (data[1] == 0) && (data[2] == 0) && (data[3] == 0))
            {
                for (int i = 4; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (zuweisung(i - 4) >= 0)
                    {
                        CheckBox c = (CheckBox)checkboxes[zuweisung(i - 4) - 1];

                        bool t = data[i] == 1 ? true : false;
                        if (c.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { c.Checked = t; }));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the code where I generate the CheckBoxes:

```
 for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                CheckBox pins = new CheckBox();

                checkboxes.Add(pins);

                pins.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
                pins.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 5F);
                pins.Location = Location = new Point(j * 20, 502 - i * 20);
                pins.Name = "pin" + ((j) + (20 * (i - 1))).ToString();
                pins.MouseHover += new EventHandler(this.pin_MouseHover);
                pins.Size = new Size(15, 15);
                pins.TabIndex = 12;
                pins.Text = " ";
                pins.BringToFront();
                pins.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                Controls.Add(pins);
                pins.Click += new EventHandler(pinsclick);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `not working`? do you get exceptions? unexpected results?

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working". Provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want. If there are error messages, be sure to provide the exact error text, and if there's an exception, the full stack trace for that exception.

Comment: `bool t = data[i] == 1 ? true : false;` == `bool t = data[i] == 1;`

Comment: inside the for - you check `zuweisung(i - 4)` more than once, so why not save it as `int allocation = zuweisung(i - 4);` and then use it in `if(allocation > 0) { }` and `CheckBox c = (CheckBox)checkboxes[allocation - 1]`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "InvokeRequired" pattern you typed misses the `else` part, in the situation where the invoke is... not required:

```
if (c.InvokeRequired)
{
    c.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { c.Checked = t; }));
}
else
{
    c.Checked = t;
}
```

**EDIT**

The `while (true)` is quite violent. I suspect this code to send a blast of UI invocation that the UI thread cannot proceed. Is it possible for you to move this in a timer instead ?

Your issue is very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440758/thread-in-c-sharp-causing-infinite-loop-and-blocks-my-application).

Comment: The state of the CheckBox are always the same

Comment: This is strange. Are you sure the data array contains the values you expect ?

Comment: Yes, because when I change the state in the main thread it works

Comment: When i but the code outside of the while(true), it doesn't change the state,but when i debug it, it says that the checkbox state has changed

Comment: How about this ?: delegate { c.Checked = t; c.Refresh(); }

Comment: Are you sure the checkbox instances in the "checkboxes" array corresponds to the displayed checkbox instances ?

Comment: I suggest to get rid with the while(true) loop and use a timer instead.

Answer (score -2):

It's quite difficult to guess what the problem might be with the provided information, but one problem might be the UI control on which you call the invoke method (possibly the form), and the checkboxes are not built on the same thread. If that is the problem, a call to c.Invoke(...) instead of Invoke can fix the problem.
Like:

```
if (c.InvokeRequired)
{
    c.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { c.Checked = t; }));
}
```